# Do I need to install Java to deploy an application in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, server, war

This question might have been asked somewhere else, but googling "does tomcat need java to run war" didn't provide the solution I am looking for.

This is the situation. I have a Java based web application as as WAR file. It is developed using Java  and several libraries like Hibernate, Java Mail and Quartz scheduler. Now, we need to deploy this to our linux server.

The Java version they used is in the below image.

[image]

I have been asked to use the Tomcat 7 because the developers of the application used the latest version of XAMPP (version 5.6.3) which you can find [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) to test and develop the application. They have used Netbeans IDE 8..0.2 as the development environment. Database will be deployed to server and it is MySQL.

Now, my question is, do I need to install Java to the server as well or just tomcat is enough? Please give me your advice.

Comment: Simple answer, yes you need Java in-order for tomcat to start.

Answer (score 3):

> do I need to install Java to the server as well or just tomcat is
>   enough

The short answer to your question is Yes.

The long answer is as follows :

> In order to use Tomcat for developing web applications, you must first
>   install it (and the software it depends on). The required steps are
>   outlined in the following subsections.
>
> JDK Tomcat 7.0 was designed to run on Java SE 6.
>
> Compatible JDKs for many platforms (or links to where they can be
>   found) are available at
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html.

Once you have installed the appropriate Java version, make sure that you set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the folder where Java is installed. Tomcat looks for JAVA_HOME when you start the server.

Comment: Note that while Tomcat 7 *requires* Java 6, Java 6 has been EOL for some time now, and Java 8 should generally be preferred.

Comment: @chrylis: so should I install Java 8?

Comment: @Dongle While there is no harm in doing that, there are a couple of changes made to Java 8 that may or may not affect the performance of your applicaiton. If things have been working fine with Java 6 for you, I would say stick to it or move the Java 7..